# How do I get the URLs to display properly when switching from the SL3 Beta?

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I was using the SL3 beta and used the Deep Linking functionality as part of my application.  When I switched to SL3, the deep linking stopped working.  What do I need to do to get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, if you add the following tag to the hosting page (html or aspx or what have you) after the object tag, it works.  You may need to update the Silverlight.js too.

```
<iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
```